# Setting Gnome extension from C shell (csh)

Tags: gnome, gsettings, csh

I want to set the enabled-extension but when I do this, it doesn't work. `echo` just prints to console and exec either say "File name too long" or shows me the usage for gsettings.

But if I copy the output from echo and manually paste it into terminal, it works.

```csh
set setClas = 'gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions '
echo $setClas$val
exec $setClas$val
```

Edit:
So I tried what @steeldriver suggested with the alias and that doesn't work either.

Just an FYI the variable val is a string that looks something like this:
"['blah blah', 'another blah blah']"

The outer double quotes are a part of the string. Does csh remove the outer double quotation marks when doing the exec? Because my command won't run without the outer quotation marks. And if so, how can I force csh to include them?

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is a *shell alias*? in `csh`, that would be defined like `alias setClas 'gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions'`. Then you should be able to use `setClas $val` to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` instead of using `exec` solved my issue.